# NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

What is NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100 ? I am getting this error while uploading image from camera in iOS build. I am working in ionic 1. How this issue can be fixed?

Comment: got same error while runing with xcode .. have u find any solution ?

Comment: @VivekChaturvedi seeing this also from cordova were you able to debug any further?

Answer (score 2):

1100 - `NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist`

Your code tries to retrieve something at wrong url.
Server says the file doesn't exist.

Comment: but the same api's and server is working for the android build

Comment: @SimerjitParmar my fault. I've fixed

Comment: @YagneshDobariya check your url. It is possible wrong

Comment: @Vyacheslav It is working fine with android but in iOS it causes error while i try to present model in success block.